# Fetch json data in Redux

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I have an action called `inAccountsList` in which I want to fetch the data from a json file I've created in my project. I import my file and now I want to fetch the data from this .json file in my action

```
import jsonData from '../data/account_list_response.json';
export const ACCOUNT_LIST = 'ACCOUNT_LIST';
export function inAccountsList() {
  const request = 

  type: ACCOUNT_LIST,
  payload: request
}
```

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have imported the JSON file already, you can just send the data in the action like this

```
const action = {
  type: ACCOUNT_LIST,
  payload: {
    data: jsonData
  }
}
```

You're not really fetching the data, just importing it from a file at compile time. You would be fetching the data if you were requesting it dynamically at run time (an ajax call to an API for example)